# mvc - model view naming compatibility

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What if we have an aspx page which resembles a model or a view (name is same)?
Can it be compatible to the conventions?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you have an aspx page that is not a View?

I have Models and Views with the same name in a current solution I am working with, namespaces generally help to keep that under control.

Comment: Means if the page is not specifically known to be view or model...then any ambiguity will come or not?

Comment: You can't have a View and a non-view aspx in the same folder as they would have the same name which is impossible so there can be no ambiguity as they would reside on different paths - don't forget Views have an .aspx extension too. Perhaps you should just try it and see if it works...